# Error while calling a PLSQL stored function having a PLSQLTable type as one of its parameter

Tags: java, jpa, plsql, eclipselink

I want to call this function

```
 function fn_validate_add_pos_profile(p_pos_pk in t_num_tab, p_profile_pk in number,p_valid_from in    date, p_valid_to in date) 
   return  t_num_num_str;
```

Here are the definition of used type

```
          create or replace type t_num_tab is table of number;

          create or replace type t_num_num_str_tab as table of t_num_num_str ;

        *************************************************
             @Embeddable 
            @PLSQLTable(name = "T_NUM_TAB" ,compatibleType = "T_NUM_TAB",nestedType = "NUMBER",javaType = Long.class)
            public class NumTypeTable extends ArrayList {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            }

    ****************************************************************************************************
```

Here is the map class to t_num_num_str_tab type

---

```
         @Embeddable
        @Struct(name ="t_num_num_str_tab",fields = {"num1","num2","str"})
        public class NumNumStrType extends ComplexDatabaseType {
        @Column(name = "num1",length = 10)
        private Long num1;
        @Column(name = "num2",length = 10)
        private Long num2;
        @Column(name = "str",length=255)
        private String str;......}
    *****************************************************************************************************
```

the method call of the plsqlstoredfunctioncall

---

```
         public List<Object> findPointOfSaleConflictList(List<Long> posIds,Long profileId, Date date){
            NumNumStrType numNumStrType= new NumNumStrType();
            numNumStrType.setCompatibleType("t_num_num_str_tab");
            numNumStrType.setJavaType(NumNumStrType.class);
            numNumStrType.setTypeName("t_num_num_str_tab");
            PLSQLStoredFunctionCall function = new PLSQLStoredFunctionCall(numNumStrType);
            function.setProcedureName("fn_validate_add_pos_profile");
            PLSQLCollection plsqlCollection = new PLSQLCollection();
            plsqlCollection.setCompatibleType("T_NUM_TAB");
            plsqlCollection.setJavaType(NumTypeTable.class);
            plsqlCollection.setTypeName("T_NUM_TAB");
            plsqlCollection.setNestedType(JDBCTypes.NUMERIC_TYPE);
            function.addNamedArgument("p_pos_pk",plsqlCollection);
            function.addNamedArgument("p_profile_pk", JDBCTypes.NUMERIC_TYPE);
            function.addNamedArgument("p_valid_from", JDBCTypes.DATE_TYPE );
            function.addNamedArgument("p_valid_to", JDBCTypes.DATE_TYPE);
            DataReadQuery readQuery=new DataReadQuery();
            readQuery.addArgument("p_pos_pk",ArrayList.class);
            readQuery.addArgument("p_profile_pk",Long.class);
            readQuery.addArgument("p_valid_from", Date.class);
            readQuery.addArgument("p_valid_to", Date.class);
            readQuery.setCall(function);
            readQuery.bindAllParameters();
            Vector args=new Vector();
            NumTypeTable myTableType=new NumTypeTable();
            myTableType.add(1);
            myTableType.add(2);
            args.add(myTableType);
            args.add(profileId);
            args.add(new Date());
            args.add(DateUtils.addYears(new Date(),99));
            Object result= ((JpaEntityManager)getEntityManager()).getActiveSession().executeQuery(readQuery,args);

            return null;
        }
    *****************************************************************************************************
```

Error Message after calling the method above

---

```
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence       Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Ungültiger Spaltentyp
    Error Code: 17004
       Call: 
      DECLARE
      p_pos_pkTARGET T_NUM_TAB;
      p_pos_pkCOMPAT T_NUM_TAB := :1;
      p_profile_pkTARGET NUMERIC := :2;
      p_valid_fromTARGET DATE := :3;
      p_valid_toTARGET DATE := :4;
      RESULTTARGET t_num_num_str_tab;
    null  FUNCTION EL_SQL2PL_3(aSqlItem T_NUM_TAB)
      RETURN T_NUM_TAB IS
        aPlsqlItem T_NUM_TAB;
      BEGIN
        IF aSqlItem.COUNT > 0 THEN
          FOR I IN 1..aSqlItem.COUNT LOOP
            aPlsqlItem(I) := aSqlItem(I);
          END LOOP;
        END IF;
        RETURN aPlsqlItem;
      END EL_SQL2PL_3;
    BEGIN
      p_pos_pkTARGET := EL_SQL2PL_3(p_pos_pkCOMPAT);
      RESULTTARGET := fn_validate_add_pos_profile(p_pos_pk=>p_pos_pkTARGET, p_profile_pk=>p_profile_pkTARGET, p_valid_from=>p_valid_fromTARGET, p_valid_to=>p_valid_toTARGET);
      :5 := EL_PL2SQL_0(RESULTTARGET);
    END;
      bind => [:1 => [1, 2], :2 => 3, :3 => 2013-12-10 17:06:00.121, :4 => 2112-12-10 17:06:00.121, RESULT => :5]
    Query: DataReadQuery()
```

Comment: Did you connect using the owner schema or not and which DB you are using?

Comment: we use oracle DB and eclipselink for ORM mapping.

Comment: Did u comment to this database with the owner schema or another schema has privilege on the owner schema?

Comment: the application ist directly connected to owner schema